# fillstyle='none' gives AssertionError

Tags: windows, python-2.7, matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04

I am fighting again in moving from Windows to Linux. I tried to recompile something I wrote at work (Win7 and python 2.7) on my Ubuntu 12.04 at home.

I guess that once again the problem is somewhere obvious, but I don't have a clue.

**Edit** I looked into my `markers.py` and it seems that `fillstyle` only has `fillstyles = ('full', 'left' , 'right' , 'bottom' , 'top')` so no `none` here. In pythonxy the `markers.py` in the matplotlib directory has the additional `'none'`, so is this an Ubuntu problem? How to solve that? Workarounds?

Minimal non-working example looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rc('font', family='serif') 
mpl.rc('font', serif='Times New Roman') 

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax=fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

x1=[1,2,3,4]
y1=[4,2,.5,.25]
ax.plot(x1,y1,marker='o', 
    color=(.6,0,0), 
    fillstyle='none',###### THIS LINE PRODUCES THE ERROR
    linewidth=0,markersize=8,markeredgewidth=2
    )
plt.show()
```

Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "short.py", line 16, in <module>
linewidth=0,markersize=8,markeredgewidth=2
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3893, in plot
for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 322, in _grab_next_args
for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 310, in _plot_args
seg = func(x[:,j%ncx], y[:,j%ncy], kw, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 260, in _makeline
self.set_lineprops(seg, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 203, in set_lineprops
func(val)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 312, in set_fillstyle
self._marker.set_fillstyle(fs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/markers.py", line 137, in set_fillstyle
assert fillstyle in self.fillstyles
AssertionError
```

In contrast  `fillstyle='left'` or `bottom`, `full`, etc works absolutely fine.

Comment: What version of `matplotlib` are you using here?

Comment: @cel OK... `mpl.__version__` says  `'1.1.1rc'`. Please don't tell me that Canonical left me again with packages from the stone age. I am really getting tired from running into this problems.

Comment: @cel Ist it [this problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/upgrade-matplotlib-to-1-2-or-1-3)?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you are on a LTS branch of ubuntu and need somewhat recent python packages, don't even think about using apt :)

Comment: @cel "somewhat recent" has a big irony sign here, I guess.

Comment: `LTS` versions only provide security updates. While this is usually fine for a server, it can be very annoying to see that all not-security critical packages are at the state of years ago. You have multiple options here: If it's just outdated python packages that annoy you: just avoid ubuntu's apt package manager. Instead use e.g. `anaconda` to get the latest scientific software packages - or: switch to the lastest non LTS version :)